# How can we detect electric field in electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism

Electromagnetic wave have magnetic and electric component but what is the proof for that? How "non electrostatic" electric field can be detected around coil?

Comment: We can make both electric and magnetic antennas. Ideally they will be responding only to one component of the field. A short dipole is an electric antenna, a small coil (relative to the wavelength) is a magnetic antenna. While these are not as efficient as well matched resonant antennas, they can still pick up these components independently and we can show the phase relationships that we expect from an electromagnetic wave.

Comment: For a radio wave the animated diagram in this Wikipedia article on Antennas shows how the electric field of the electromagnetic wave exerts a force on the electrons in the antenna and hence sents up currents and voltages in the antenna.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)

Comment: In principle you could observe motion of a charged object due to the electric field of a radio wave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any electric charge would experience a force due to an electric field. Therefore, the electric field in electromagnetic waves produces currents in antennas. It happens all the time in wireless communication.

In the case of an electrostatically charged dielectric such as a plastic foil, the charges would tend to polarize the charges in any uncharged dielectric material that it comes in contact with. Any charge has a static electric field around it. This electric field produces an attractive or repulsive force depending on the sign of the charges involved. So, say the eletrostatically charged dielectric contains positive charges. Then it would attract negative charges and repulse positive charges in the uncharged dielectric. This causes polarization. The negative charges would now attract the positively charged dielectric. One observes this phenomenon as the tendency of electrostatically charged material to cling to things.

Comment: "electric charge would experience a force due to an electric field" what do you mean by that? when I place charged foil near coil with time varying current ,foil will experience force? repulsive ,attractive?

Comment: The charges within the coil will experience a force and so the free electrons in the foil wil move and so a current is produced in the foil.  That is how an induction furnace works.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_heating

Comment: no no,the foil is made of plastic and charged electrostaticly,so?

Comment: @szufla, are you asking why an electric field would cause an electric charge to feel a force in general? Or as you in particular interested in the case when this electrostatically charged foil is placed in an electric field?

Comment: the second one,an charged plastic foil is placed near pulsating coil that emits EMF (induced electric field) or rotating magnet, like so:
http://maxwellsociety.net/images/FaradayParadox/image565.gif

Comment: @szufla. See the edited answer.